# Switch between two events at a given rate

Tags: javascript

I want to switch between 2 .js files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var jsfiles = ['/js/green.js', '/js/blue.js'];

var randomLink = Math.floor(Math.random() * jsfiles.length);

document.getElementById('scriptid').src = jsfiles[randomLink];
//-->
</script>
<script src="" id="scriptid"></script>
```

How to make green.js occur 98% of the time and blue.js the other 2% of the time?

Comment: You'd have to keep persistent counters somewhere to accurately achieve that.

Comment: If you really have 2 files you can try generating a random number between 0-100, and everything under 98 will select green.js, but it isn't really 98%... will probably become more like 99%...

Comment: Well i just want to switch between 1 or the other at those rates, I thought that using Math.random and another thing that I'm not aware of would do the trick.

Comment: @eric.itzhak how so? can you give me an example? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something simple like this? That would give 98%/2% all the time.

```
var jsfiles = ['/js/green.js', '/js/blue.js'],
    secondFileCount = 0,
    count = 0,
    rndFiles = [],
    num;

while (count < 100) {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

    if (num !== 1 || secondFileCount++ <= 2)
        count = rndFiles.push(jsfiles[num]);
}

console.log(rndFiles);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4BfWS/)

Comment: Nice, I understand it, now how to apply that to this? `<script src="" id="scriptid"></script>` Thanks!

Comment: @JoseCardama Well, do you want this to go on indefinitely? Without changing much of my code, you could wrap this process in a function, then pop every `rndFiles` element and when the array is empty, re-run the process to generate another 100 files streak.

Comment: I just want that from 100 times that the document is loaded, 98 times src="/js/green.js" and 2 times src="/js/green.js"

Comment: @JoseCardama Well, just `pop` values from `rndFiles` which already contains the good ratio and use the popped value as the source for your script.

Comment: When `document.getElementById('scriptid').src = rndFiles;` it throws me the whole list from your original code.

Comment: @JoseCardama Pop the files one by one, `var nextFile = rndFiles.pop();`

Comment: Thanks, now if you want to modify those percentages what would I need to do?

Comment: @JoseCardama You could simply change the `secondFileCount++ <= 2` condition to reflect the percentage of the second file. Right now it's 2%.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try and achive something that may seem like 98%, if the actuall percent doesn't really matter you can try doing

```
var jsfiles = ['/js/green.js', '/js/blue.js'];

var randumNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

if(randomNum > 90)
    document.getElementById('scriptid').src = '/js/blue.js';
 else
    document.getElementById('scriptid').src = '/js/green.js';
```

That's not a really good solution, as it's won't actually be 98%, the way random behaves is different and it won't be accurate, but if you only have 2 files and the actuall percentage doesn't matter, this can work.

I've set `> 90` as I think that if you go on `98`, this will be something like 99%, but it's not a fact i'm not sure how exactly randomize works in JS, your call.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

`if ((~~(Math.random()*100))<=98) alert('in the 98 zone'); else alert('in the 2 zone')`

Comment: three is a boundry edge scenario here since I can ever get 100. but that's the main idea.